# What is the word or a phrase for people who are unable to be categorized into groups?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

What is the word or a phrase for people who are unable to be categorized into groups or stereotyped?

Perhaps non-(something)

I am not looking for the word unique.

Thank you

Comment: Probably not even worthy of a comment because they’re usually (and understandably) found in “scare quotes,” but if it doesn’t bother you (or your intended audience) that “non[-]pigeonholable” or “un[-]pigeonholable” are not real words, you could consider one of them for a single “word.”  For a phrase, with “pigeonhole/d/ing” in mind, you could consider “[being] impossible to pigeonhole”/“incapable of being pigeonholed”/”[not /in]susceptible to pigeonholing.”

Comment: Often categorized as *other*.

Comment: If you are calling that collection of people something, you are categorizing them into a group, so they are able to be categorized.  You're just looking for a generic name for the category, like "other".

Comment: There was a whole movie series about this, [Divergent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergent_(film)) based of course on a series of books.

Comment: *non-existent* as in, the concept does not exist in reality. I've never met anyone that I couldn't label.

Answer (score 9):

Consider ***outliers***.

ODO:

> **[outlier](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/outlier)**
>   *NOUN*
>
> **1.1** A person or thing differing from all other members of a particular group or set.
>
> ‘In groups it's often the non-expert, the outlier, or the person who
>   isn't in charge who has the most interesting idea.’

Comment: "all *other* members", whatever group of which they are one.

Answer (score 8):

You can describe someone as being **atypical** (i.e. not typical), which means **unusual** (another word you could use). You can also say that someone *conforms* to a stereotype or social norm; if they don't then you can say that they are **nonconformist**, or **unorthodox**.

If someone exhibits unusual behaviours, you can describe them as **idiosyncratic**.

If someone stands out, or is especially noticeable, because of their being different you can describe them as **distinctive**.

If someone is especially unusual then you can describe them as being **one of a kind** ([One of a kind](http://merriam-webster.com/dictionary/one%20of%20a%20kind) : a person or thing that is not like any other person or thing) - thanks to [@EnglishStudent](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/231519/english-student) for pointing this one out.

Comment: ***One of a kind*** :  a person or thing that is not like any other person or thing https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/one%20of%20a%20kind

Comment: @EnglishStudent Mind if I add that to my answer?

Comment: you can do so purely because you asked for it! Go ahead and add it...

Comment: in AE you could  also add "Outlier" and also the most common an "outsider"  
"a person who is excluded, or excludes himself, from some group; outsider"

Comment: Very nice answer which gives some interesting choices for OP! I also remembered the expression 'broke the mould' as in "*he is one of a kind: they **broke the mould** when they made him!*" http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/They+broke+the+mould+when+they+made

Answer (score 3):

The most precise term for this, I think, is *sui generis*, which is Latin for "in a class of its own". It even has [its own Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sui_generis). The
[on-line Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sui%20generis) gives this example:

> among history's greats Leonardo da Vinci is often considered sui
>   generis—a man of such stupendous genius that the world may never see
>   his like again

Answer (score 0):

To add to the other answers: *singular* and *one-off* may be applied to people.

Answer (score 0):

I think *eccentrics* might fit... unless you consider that labeling someone as "eccentric" assigns them to a group, defeating your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Given that stereotypical is the best way to describe people that fit into a group, I would simply say *non-stereotypical*.

I'm a bit surprised no one has mentioned this so far. It should be the obvious answer.

Answer (score -3):

Sounds like *ineffable* might work.

```
ineffable |inˈefəb(ə)l|
adjective
too great or extreme to be expressed or described in words: the ineffable natural beauty of the Everglades.
```